# send a net send type popup to all users 1 day a week on my network

Tags: popup, modalpopupextender

I'm looking to send a net send type message popup to all users in my network 1 day week every week.

Can I do this via Windows somwhow or would I need a script running somewhere?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `net send` an option?

Comment: Is the message going to be a static message every week, or is it something dynamic/manual?

Comment: Even if net send is not an option.  Create a winform application in C# / VB.net with whatever content.  Throw it on a server and have the app issue a command to each pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to ensure the net send service is allowed to run control panel->services.
So check that services for the service that controls net send.  Than you simply create a batch file and issue a net send command.  You place that batch file on a server and use windows scheduler to schedule the batch job to run once a week.

Comment: Hi Yeah I reckon this is the best way to do this. Was thinking maybe a program. Unfortunately messenger has been disabled on all pcs but once rectified we'll do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@thegunner, I believe you will find that almost all modern Windows machines have the Messenger service disabled.  You would need to sort that out to be able to use the [`net send`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_send) command (and tie that together with the [`at`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Windows%29) command, for example, to automate/schedule your message.)

Are you sure that a popup is the most appropriate method of delivering your message?  I know that, for example, I can be in the middle of typing this answer to you and if some other app pops up a dialog (just like `net send` would) I can very easily dismiss that popup without intending to, without having seen what it was and no way to get it back.  This happens rather more than I would like in Windows because popups are allowed to "steal" focus from the current app in which I am working.  Most frustrating.